# TimeSeriesGenerator with many to one LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Im attempting to generate data for my many-to-one LSTM in Tensorflow's 2 using Keras. However, the TimeSeriesGenerator requires that the data and target arguments be the same length. How would one generate many-to-one data with the TimeSeriesGenerator?

Comment: Did you find a solution?